# Order of abelianized group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

In a proof that I am reading the author wants to determine the order of the abelianized group $G / [G,G] $ of a group $G$ with a presentation with $n$ generators and $n$ relations.

The author states that this order is the absolute value of the determinant of the $n\times n$ relation matrix.

Can anyone give me a reference for such a theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the page number but you'll find it in D. L. Johnson's, *"Presentation$\color{red}{s}$ of Groups"* with ISBN 0 521 20829 7.

Comment: Thanks alot. Unfortunately the statement is there as an exercise on page 85.

Comment: You're welcome, @user744043.

Comment: Are you sure, @user744043? I just checked page 85 of my copy and didn't find it, although similar results are on page 185.

Comment: I think I have a really early edition . . .